# generalize function pointers

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Yesterday night I've written the following piece of code to perform some arithmetical operation (sum, multiplication, subtraction, division).

```
 data operation(int oper, data e1, data e2){
   data res;
   basic b;
   //pointer to a funcion that takes two int input and return an int
   int (*funIntPtr)(int,int);
   float (*funFloatPtr)(float,float);

   funIntPtr = NULL;
   funFloatPtr= NULL;
   //I look for the function to be called
     switch (oper) {
       case MINUS:
         //*functionPtr = &subInt;
         switch (e1.b.type) {
           case basic_int_value:funIntPtr = subInt;break;
           case basic_float_value:funFloatPtr = subFloat;break;
           case basic_boolean_value:
             yyerror("boolean arithmetic operation are NOT_ALLOWED");
             exit(NOT_ALLOWED);
             break;
         }
         break;
       case PLUS :
         switch (e1.b.type) {
           case basic_int_value:funIntPtr = addInt;break;
           case basic_float_value:funFloatPtr = addFloat;break;
           case basic_boolean_value:
             yyerror("boolean arithmetic operation are NOT_ALLOWED");
             exit(NOT_ALLOWED);
             break;
         }
         break;
       case MULTIPLY:
         switch (e1.b.type) {
           case basic_int_value:funIntPtr = mulInt;break;
           case basic_float_value:funFloatPtr = mulFloat;break;
           case basic_boolean_value:
             yyerror("boolean arithmetic operation are NOT_ALLOWED");
             exit(NOT_ALLOWED);
             break;
         }
         break;
       case DIVIDE :
         switch (e1.b.type) {
           case basic_int_value:funIntPtr = divInt;break;
           case basic_float_value:funFloatPtr = divFloat;break;
           case basic_boolean_value:
             yyerror("boolean arithmetic operation are NOT_ALLOWED");
             exit(NOT_ALLOWED);
             break;
         }
         break;
       default:
         yyerror("what now?");
         exit(BUGGY_THE_CLOWN);
         break;
      }
    //look for values to be used
    if( funIntPtr == NULL && funFloatPtr == NULL){
      yyerror("no function found for the specified operation..");
      exit(BUGGY_THE_CLOWN);
    }
    res.type = basic_dataType;
    res.b.type = e1.b.type;//inherithed
    switch (e1.b.type) {
      case basic_int_value:
        {
          res.b.i = funIntPtr(e1.b.i, e2.b.i);
        }
        break;
      case basic_float_value:
        {
          res.b.f = funFloatPtr(e1.b.f, e2.b.f);
        }
        break;
      case basic_boolean_value:
      default:
        yyerror("no data found for the specified operation..");
        exit(BUGGY_THE_CLOWN);
    }
   return res;
 }
```

In the first part I find the function to be used and in the second part I collect the input data to be used. It works fine and it serves the purpose.

```
typedef struct data{
    dataType type;
    union{
      complex c;
      basic b;
    };
}data;
```

data is a struct which contains either basic types values or complex values. Complex values are array types and structures. About which, for the moment, I don't care.

```
typedef struct basic{
  basicType type;
  union{
     int i;
     float f;
     bool b;
  };
}basic;
```

Basic values atm contains just integers, floats and booleans.

But I was wondering if I can make it more compact and efficient.
For example I have declared two function pointer but I use only one of them. Is there any way to generalize the function pointer?

I know I have to declare the input types and return type, but in this case it would be great to defer such function specialization in order to have only one pointer.
Is it possible or should I change the way I'm tackling the problem?

Any constructive suggestion is well accepted :)

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. What is `data`?

Comment: In the first part, you could choose a `struct {  int (*funIntPtr)(int,int); float (*funFloatPtr)(float,float); }`, and leave the type checking to the second part.

Comment: You have copy/paste issues in `case DIVIDE` (it's the same as `case MULTIPLY`) and also you should trap divide by 0.

Comment: @WeatherVane typecheking happens before this function call and I assume I can not divide by zero, there are also int division problems around but that's quite ok for the example. Question is now updated as requested with more information..

Comment: @LMG I see you have edited `case DIVIDE` but basic errors like that make me lose confidence in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your example I don't see the float function used:

```
  case basic_float_value:
    {
      res.b.i = funIntPtr(e1.b.i, e2.b.i);
    }
```

I would expect something like:

```
  case basic_float_value:
    {
      res.b.f = funFloatPtr(e1.b.f, e2.b.f);
    }
```

And this is exactly why you can't use a single function pointer: there is a huge difference in how float (double) and integer parameters are passed to the function and how the result is returned. Of course you could do heavy casting, just to save a function pointer, but that would obfuscate the code so I advice against that.

Comment: Note: before calling the function you must check that both operands your parser read are of the correct type, or you must cast/convert them to that type; for example, e2 has an int value and e1 has a float value requires the call `funFloatPtr(e1.b.f, e2.b.i);`

Comment: type checking happens before this function call, so since there is not coercion provided yet, they are assumed to be of the same type..

Comment: so you are saying "Of course you could do heavy casting, just to save a function pointer, but that would obfuscate the code so I advice against that.", that is better having a readable code rather than a compact one?

Comment: Yes, always. Readable code is maintainable; compact code not always. Readable compact code is of course best.

Answer (score 0):

You may use folowing structure:

```
/* Operations enum */
enum operation {
    ADD, SUB, DIV, MUL, OP_COUNT
};

/* Operation arity */
static const int arity[OP_COUNT] = {
    [ADD] = 2, [SUB] = 2, [DIV] = 2, [MUL] = 2
};

/* Operation function pointer */
typedef double (*Operator)(double* arguments);

/* Map operation to operator */
Operator operators[OP_COUNT] = {
    [ADD] = add, [SUB] = sub, [DIV] = div, [MUL] = mul
};

double add(double *arguments) { return arguments[0] + arguments[1]; }
/* and so on for other operators */
```

Also, you may want to combine `arity` and `operators` maps.

One more thing is that declaring a static array for arguments may require knowing the maximum amongst `arity` values. This structure will let you implement any-arity  operators without having much code rewrite.

Also, instead of `double` you can use any generalized value structure you want.